# Stringr - removing leading zero from both sides of hyphen

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Per title, I am looking for a way to remove the leading zero from both sides of the hyphen.

```
codes <- c("0002-01014", "0020-0014","00014-00010")
want <- c("2-1014","20-14","14-10")
```

I suppose one can split the numbers into two, remove leading zero, then paste together, but I was wondering if there is more refined method using single step of `str_extract()`, `str_replace()`, or similars.

Edit:

I am currently using

```
str_split("0002-01010","-",simplify=T) %>%
  str_replace("^0+(?!$)", "") %>%
  str_c(collapse="-")
```

and was curious if there is an alternative method that can be achieved in single line.

Comment: Perhaps this will work: `stringr::str_replace_all(codes, "\\b0+","")`

Comment: And what about `0000-1111`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I am currently using `str_split("0002-01010","-",simplify=T) %>%
  str_replace("^0+(?!$)", "") %>%
  str_c(collapse="-")` to result `2-1010` and was curious if there is a single-line method.

As for second comment, that would be `0-1111`

Comment: `(^|-)0+` seems like it would work. and your replacement should be just capture group #1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
codes <- c("0002-01014", "0020-0014","00014-00010", "00000-122345")
gsub("\\b0+\\B", "", codes, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "2-1014"   "20-14"    "14-10"    "0-122345"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/XcVbkw) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TU5KsH/2).

The `\b` matches a position between start of string or a non-word char and a word char, here, at the beginning of the string or between `-` and the next digit. `0+` matches one or more zeros, as many as possible. `\B` makes sure the match stops before a digit, so it there are only zeros in the number, the last one remains intact.

Answer (score 1):

You might as well match and remove zeros at the beginning or after a dash, but not at the end or before a dash:

```r
codes <- c("0002-01014", "0020-0014","00014-00010", "00000-000330")
gsub("(^|-)0+(?!-|$)", "\\1", codes, perl=TRUE)
```

See [R proof](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pzk/JbVYwUZXIVlDycDAwEjXwNDA0ERJRwHIMzLQNQBzQDKGJrog0gAiBQQgrrGxgZImV3pxaZKGkkZcja6mgbaGvaJujYomSFlMjCGQAtugo1CQWpRjGxIU6qr5/z8A). See the [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/hPhOYy/1).

**Expression explanation**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0+                       '0' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```